# SharePoint Search on default Masterpage

Tags: sharepoint, search, master-pages

I am trying to enable the search bar on my default master page.  In the source code of the master page there is the following:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox"/>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

In the render of the page in design mode it says [DelegateControl].  When I publish the page, I do not see a search box, I see nothing... can someone point me in the direction as how to enable search on my default master page, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem but eventually found a very simple solution.  You just need to make sure your asp:ContentPlaceHolder is within an html form.  I don't know exactly why this is the case, but simply changing your code to

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
  <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox"/>
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

should solve the problem.

I found this very simple application.master page: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/justguy/archive/2008/08/31/empty-application-master.aspx

When the search boxes worked using this simple master page, I was able to track down the problem and find the needed  element.

Comment: Brilliant, this worked for me! Someone should set this is a correct solution pronto :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you MOSS Search service is correctly configured?

If not, check this article:
http://www.mysharepointblog.com/post/2008/10/Configure-Search-On-MOSS-2007-(Microsoft-Office-SharePoint-Server).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the "Office SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features" from the site features?